# Symfony 4 webpack + encore handle image in template

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

Using Symfony 4 with Webpack + Encore + Yarn, I want to handle images in my templates, and I am not really how to achieve this.

I put my image in my `/assets/img/logo.png` folder, and use this in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
.addEntry('logo', './assets/img/logo.png')
```

And after I run :

```
yarn run encore dev
```

Which generates `/public/build/logo.js` and `/public/build/images/logo.aez323a.png` files.

My question, is there a way to link Symfony `asset()` function to the file name with the hash in the filename ? or should I use other way to use the image in my templates ?

Comment: I found another way. Add CopyPlugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/49183966/7478675

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you have enabled the versioning `.enableVersioning()` , each time you run `yarn run encore dev` a **manifest.json** file should be created in your output path, based on your question this path is **/public/build**. So you will have to add in your settings the following configuration

**config/packages/framework.yaml**

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

Then you will be able to use the `asset()` function referencing by name e.g `asset('public/images/logo.png')`

You can find this information in symfony documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/versioning.html)

Comment: Very nice and clean answer, I didn't find it in the doc, my bad.

Comment: Also i think you would be interested in this conversation on wehbpack-encore git repository https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/24 it is about handling static assets with webpack

Answer (score 0):

There is copyFiles now - official encore plugin:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html

In short, you put images in /assets/images (or any other), at build time plugin copy this folder to /public/build with same subfolder structure. All you need to do is add some strings to /webpack.config.js - plugin activation with "from" and "to" variables.

In twig use those images as usual with {{ asset(**path_in_public**) }}.

if you enable dev server for hot reload

```sh
$ yarn encore dev-server
```

than files from /assets/images will be available in twig templates even without physical copy in /public.

Files will be physically copied when you execute

```sh
$ yarn encore prod
```