# symfony 4 webpack + encore handle image in template more info

Tags: image, symfony, templates, webpack, symfony4

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042006/symfony-4-webpack-encore-handle-image-in-template):

> Using Symfony 4 with Webpack + Encore + Yarn, I want to handle images
> in my templates, and I am not really how to achieve this.
>
> I put my image in my /assets/img/logo.png folder, and use this in my
> webpack.config.js:
>
> .addEntry('logo', './assets/img/logo.png')
>
> And after I run :
>
> yarn run encore dev
>
> Which generates /public/build/logo.js and
> /public/build/images/logo.aez323a.png files.

I would like to know:

What is the "logo.js" for?

And how can I keep my directory structure. For example if I have:

```
img/folder1/folder2/img.png
```

I want to keep this structure and not get everything in build/image

Thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a good solution to handle the images or other files into the template.

Here -> https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/webpack-encore/copy-plugin

Step 1: Install the plugin

```
yarn add copy-webpack-plugin --dev
```

Step 2: Config the webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

Step 3: Tell webpack where is your folder (example here static, can be img or anything)

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        // copies to {output}/static
        { from: './assets/static', to: 'static' }
]))
```

Step 4: run encore

```
yarn run encore dev
```

All your folders and files into "static" (for the example) will be copy into the "Public/build" folder!!!

Voilà voilà