# Symfony 4 - Encore - copy folder to dist

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

I use Symfony 4 + Encore / Webpack. I want to copy an entire folder (containing images) to the dist folder.

Here is my webpack config :

```
Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {}, {
        resolveUrlLoader: false
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('js/home', './assets/js/home.js')
    .addEntry('js/map', './assets/js/map.js')
    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        // copies all images
        { from: './assets/images/*', to: 'images/', flatten: true },
    ]))
```

And the images folder is not copied. I have a default installation of Symfony 4.

Is there a way to copy a folder and its assets to the dist folder in an easy way ? Using Encore without plugin ?

**EDIT**

Ok for now I will use a kind of trick, I don't understand why Symfony doesn't provide any clear documentation on images / statics management.

I put this in my main js file :

```
const imagesContext = require.context('../images', true, /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|webp)$/);
imagesContext.keys().forEach(imagesContext);
```

More informations : http://aerendir.me/2018/04/06/managin-static-images-webpack-encore/

It works perfectly and put all images from /assets/images folder to **/public/build/images** folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony 4 webpack + encore handle image in template more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156963/symfony-4-webpack-encore-handle-image-in-template-more-info)